# GIT не обновляет данные в удалённом репозитории

Tags: git, intellij-idea, контроль-версий

С недавнего времени обнаружилась следующая проблема: не обновляются данные в удалённом репозитории. С develop'ом работают два разработчика (по очереди сливают ветки в develop и выпускают релизы). Работа происходит в **Intellij IDEA**. Чтобы была ясна суть проблемы, приведу пример:

[image: Ветки идентичны, но на самом деле удалённый репозиторий содержит изменения]

**Разработчик №1** встаёт в локальный develop, сливает ветки из удалённого репозитория в локальный develop, после чего делает push изменений в удалённый develop.

**Разработчик №2** встаёт в свой локальный develop, сверяет его с удалённым (в который **Разработчик №1** уже влил изменения), т.е. делает Compare with Current в IDE, и не видит изменений. При этом неважно, сколько времени пройдёт после внесения изменений **Разработчиком №1**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом при через **Update Project** (git pull/fetch) изменения выкачиваются из удалённого develop'а.

Вопрос: почему не подтягиваются изменения из удалённого репозитория? Как настроить git таким образом, чтобы были видны изменения без слияния?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы были видны изменения **без слияния** перед Compare with Current нужно сделать просто **git fetch**, без pull.

Цитата: "*Важно отметить, что команда fetch забирает данные в ваш локальный репозиторий, но не сливает их с какими-либо вашими наработками и не модифицирует то, над чем вы работаете в данный момент. Вам необходимо вручную слить эти данные с вашими, когда вы будете готовы.*"

Ссылка на цитату:

https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8#Fetch-%D0%B8-Pull